# Problems adding new property to existing node with Neo4jClient

Tags: neo4j, neo4jclient

My beginner problems with using Neo4jClient unfortunately continues :) I have a simple class WorkEntity for which I have an update query:

```
public class WorkEntity
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string StartDate { get; set; }
    public string EndDate { get; set; }
}

var query = graphClient.Cypher
            .Match("(work:Work)", "(city:City)", "(profession:Profession)", "(company:Company)", "(oldCompany:Company)", "(oldProfession:Profession)", "(oldCity:City)",
            "(user:User)-[r1]->work", "work-[r2]->oldProfession", "work-[r3]->oldCompany", "work-[r4]->oldCity")
            .Where((WorkEntity work) => work.Id == model.Id)
            .AndWhere((CityEntity city) => city.Id == model.CityId)
            .AndWhere((CityEntity oldCity) => oldCity.Id == oldModel.CityId)
            .AndWhere((ProfessionEntity profession) => profession.Id == model.ProfessionId)
            .AndWhere((ProfessionEntity oldProfession) => oldProfession.Id == oldModel.ProfessionId)
            .AndWhere((CompanyEntity company) => company.Id == model.CompanyId)
            .AndWhere((CompanyEntity oldCompany) => oldCompany.Id == oldModel.CompanyId)
            .AndWhere("type(r1) = 'CURRENT'")
            .AndWhere("type(r2) = 'WORK_AS_PROFESSION'")
            .AndWhere("type(r3) = 'WORK_AT_COMPANY'")
            .AndWhere("type(r4) = 'WORK_IN_CITY'")
            .Set("work = {updatedWork}")
            .WithParam("updatedWork", updatedEntity);

        //If Date has been set delete current relationships
        if (oldModel.EndDate == DateTime.MinValue && model.EndDate > DateTime.MinValue)
        {
            query = query.Delete("r1");
        }
        if (oldModel.ProfessionId != model.ProfessionId)
        {
            query = query.Delete("r2")
                .CreateUnique("work-[:WORK_AS_PROFESSION]->profession");
        }
        if (oldModel.CompanyId != model.CompanyId)
        {
            query = query.Delete("r3")
                .CreateUnique("work-[:WORK_AT_COMPANY]->company");
        }
        if (oldModel.CityId != model.CityId)
        {
            query = query.Delete("r4")
               .CreateUnique("work-[:WORK_IN_CITY]->city");
        }

        query.ExecuteWithoutResults();
```

Modifying all the relationsships works as expected but if for example Description is null from the beginning above query won't add Description to an existing entity (or update any other of the properties) even though it is set in updatedEntity. If I simplify the query as below Description is added/removed and existing changed properties are updated correctly. How can that be? I really would prefer to do the whole query in one transaction.

```
 var query = graphClient.Cypher
            .Match("(work:Work)")
            .Where((WorkEntity work) => work.Id == model.Id)
            .Set("work = {updatedWork}")
            .WithParam("updatedWork", updatedEntity);
```

Comment: Could you get and post the query text generated by your fluent query? That way people less familiar with `Neo4jClient` may be able to help. I think `query.Query.QueryText` and `.QueryParameters` should do it.

Comment: I've replicated it as close as I could, but I've been unable to get this to *not* happen. i.e. if I start with a description set, it gets removed if the updated is set to null, and vice versus for it not being set initially. My gist: https://gist.github.com/cskardon/9232034 covers what I've done to replicate (I copied your code verbatim) when I look in N4J, I find my 'work' node has been updated correctly - could you try the gist and see what you get?

Comment: Thanks Chris!! I have been playing around with the gist and if you leave any of city, profession or company pointing to the same entity in model and oldModel the problem is reproduced. `var model = new { Id = "id-1", CityId = 1, ProfessionId = 2, CompanyId = 3, UserId = 4, EndDate = DateTime.MinValue };`
`var oldModel = new { Id = "id-1", CityId = 1, ProfessionId = 6, CompanyId = 7, UserId = 8, EndDate = DateTime.MinValue };`

Comment: Do you get the relationships changing as well? If I run with `CityId` set to 1 in both my model and oldmodel - I get no changes in relationships *or* nodes

Comment: Yes I have the same behaviour here, the query does not seem to work at all if at least one relationship is kept the same in model/oldmodel. No exceptions thrown, the query just silently fails to do what it is supposed to do :( So I suppose two entities of the same type for example company and oldCompany cannot point to the same company entity in the query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Chris, I realise that my understanding for Neo4j is still quite limited :) Your suggestion above updates the work entity properties correctly but not the relationsships. I don't really get why the work-[r4]-oldCity relationship doesn't match anything but anyway I took advantage of your note about this and after some trial and error finally got the query to work correctly like:

```
        var oldModel = GetWorkModel(model.Id);
        var updatedEntity = Mapper.Map<WorkEntity>(model);

        var query = graphClient.Cypher
            .Match("(work:Work)", "(city:City)", "(profession:Profession)", "(company:Company)",
                "(user:User)-[r1:CURRENT]->work", "work-[r2:WORK_AS_PROFESSION]->()", "work-[r3:WORK_AT_COMPANY]->()", "work-[r4:WORK_IN_CITY]->()")
            .Where((WorkEntity work) => work.Id == model.Id)
            .AndWhere((CityEntity city) => city.Id == model.CityId)
            .AndWhere((ProfessionEntity profession) => profession.Id == model.ProfessionId)
            .AndWhere((CompanyEntity company) => company.Id == model.CompanyId)
            .Set("work = {updatedWork}")
            .WithParam("updatedWork", updatedEntity);

        if (oldModel.EndDate == DateTime.MinValue && model.EndDate > DateTime.MinValue)
            query = query.Delete("r1");
        if (oldModel.ProfessionId != model.ProfessionId)
            query = query.Delete("r2").CreateUnique("work-[:WORK_AS_PROFESSION]->profession");
        if (oldModel.CompanyId != model.CompanyId)
            query = query.Delete("r3").CreateUnique("work-[:WORK_AT_COMPANY]->company");
        if (oldModel.CityId != model.CityId)
            query = query.Delete("r4").CreateUnique("work-[:WORK_IN_CITY]->city");

        query.ExecuteWithoutResults();
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the reason the query does nothing when the `CityId`s are the same in my gist is because the `MATCH` clause:

```
work-[r4]-oldCity
```

is not matching anything, so the match fails and the query does nothing.

In effect - if I get this right - you're attempting two queries:

1. Update `work`
2. Delete & Create new relationships

I think you should check out the `WITH` keyword, as it should help your query...

`WITH` allows you to chain your cypher queries together, so you could change your query to:

```
var query = Client.Cypher
    .Match("(work:Work)")
    .Where((WorkEntity work) => work.Id == model.Id)
    .Set("work = {updatedWork}")
    .With("work")
    .Match("(city:City)", "(profession:Profession)", "(company:Company)", "(oldCompany:Company)", "(oldProfession:Profession)", "(oldCity:City)",
        "(user:User)-[r1]->work", "work-[r2]->oldProfession", "work-[r3]->oldCompany", "work-[r4]->oldCity")
    .Where((WorkEntity work) => work.Id == model.Id)
    .AndWhere((CityEntity city) => city.Id == model.CityId)
    .AndWhere((CityEntity oldCity) => oldCity.Id == oldModel.CityId)
    .AndWhere((ProfessionEntity profession) => profession.Id == model.ProfessionId)
    .AndWhere((ProfessionEntity oldProfession) => oldProfession.Id == oldModel.ProfessionId)
    .AndWhere((CompanyEntity company) => company.Id == model.CompanyId)
    .AndWhere((CompanyEntity oldCompany) => oldCompany.Id == oldModel.CompanyId)
    .AndWhere("type(r1) = 'CURRENT'")
    .AndWhere("type(r2) = 'WORK_AS_PROFESSION'")
    .AndWhere("type(r3) = 'WORK_AT_COMPANY'")
    .AndWhere("type(r4) = 'WORK_IN_CITY'")
    .WithParam("updatedWork", updatedEntity);
```

This will execute the update and then the rest.

Another keyword that might be worth a look would be `MERGE` but I think `WITH` should help you out here.